# initialization from incompatible pointer type when assigning a pointer to a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

```
int main()
{ 
    char artist1[4][80] = {};
    char artist2[4][80] = {};
    char (*pb1)[4][80] = artist1;
    char (*pb2)[4][80] = artist2;

    char *arrptr[2] = {pb1, pb2};
    
}
```

I am trying to assign a pointer to an 2d array so I can sort move the array based on the pointer. I've done this with integer arrays and it worked fine. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `pb1` and `pb2` are not `char*`

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when  asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Aside: Those empty initialized lists are not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters these initializers of the arrays

```
char artist1[4][80] = {};
char artist2[4][80] = {};
```

are invalid in  C before the C23 Standard. You may not use empty braces.

You could write for example

```
char artist1[4][80] = { 0 };
char artist2[4][80] = { 0 };
```

In this declarations

```
char (*pb1)[4][80] = artist1;
char (*pb2)[4][80] = artist2;
```

the initializing expressions `artist1` and `artist2` have the type `char ( * )[80]` due to the implicit conversion of arrays to pointers to their first elements while the initialized objects have the type `char ( * )[4][80]`. So the compiler issues a message because there is no implicit conversion between objects of these pointer types.

You should write either

```
char (*pb1)[4][80] = &artist1;
char (*pb2)[4][80] = &artist2;
```

or (preferable)

```
char (*pb1)[80] = artist1;
char (*pb2)[80] = artist2;
```

This declaration

```
char *arrptr[2] = {pb1, pb2};
```

is also wrong.

If you will declare the pointers like

```
char (*pb1)[80] = artist1;
char (*pb2)[80] = artist2;
```

then the above declaration will look like

```
char ( *arrptr[2] )[80] = {pb1, pb2};
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not pointers. To take a pointer to an array use "address-of" operator `&`.

```
    char (*pb1)[4][80] = &artist1;
    char (*pb2)[4][80] = &artist2;
```

Moreover, the declaration of `arrptr` must be be an array of pointer to 2d arrays.

```
char (*arrptr[2])[4][80] = { pb1, pb2 };
```

The declaration is parsed as:

```
arrptr                   - arrptr is ...
arrptr[2]                - ... 2-element array of ...
(*arrptr[2])             - ... pointers to ...
(*arrptr[2])[4]          - ... 4-element array of ...
(*arrptr[2])[4][80]      - ... 80-element array of ...
char (*arrptr[2])[4][80] - ... char
```

Comment: @A Kindly mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the ✔️.

Comment: i can mark it in 6 mins

Comment: It is absolutely correct that arrays are not pointers, but they do *decay* to pointers in most expressions.  It's unclear what the OP really wants here, but in my experience of similar situations, that is most commonly to use the pointer type to which the array decays, not a pointer to the array's own type.